# Swap position of entities in the list

Tags: python

I have a following example list

```
   x= [['True_304', 'false_2'], ['True_702', 'false_2_1'], ['True_204', 'false_222_2']]
```

I would like to swap the positions of entities so that the second entity is first and first one is second. Basically, something like:

```
   x= [['false_2', 'True_304'], ['false_2_1', 'True_702'], ['false_222_2', 'True_204']]
```

Is there any easier way to do this? Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
>>> x = [['True_304', 'false_2'], ['True_702', 'false_2_1'], ['True_204', 'false_222_2']]
>>> [[b, a] for [a, b] in x]
[['false_2', 'True_304'], ['false_2_1', 'True_702'], ['false_222_2', 'True_204']]
```

Comment: Nice. Very clean and elegant.

Comment: As a side note, I think I would just write `[[b,a] for a,b in x]`.

Comment: Thanks that is really elegant and helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

And in case your list is larger than 2, e.g. 12 elements:

```
for e in x:
    e.reverse()
```